# Making JavaFX compile to Java 1.6 level source code

Tags: netbeans, javafx

How do I make JavaFX with netbeans compile my code to 1.6 level compliance.

At the moment it seems to be hard coded to 1.5 levels - stopping me from using useful tools in java.awt.Desktop (and the like)

Answer (score 1):

Remember - because JavaFX must run on the Apple Java run-time which currently is Java 1.5 - JavaFX can't compile to Java 1.6.

Thus it likely will change in the future so that it can compile to Java 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good explanation by Stephen Chin: http://steveonjava.com/2009/01/02/hacking-javafx-10-to-use-java-16-features/

Also, Steve's blog on JavaFX is great if you're getting into the new language.